# Change Language in CP

Tags: control-panel, multilingual

I am developing a site for a German client.

Is there a way to set the language of a member group?

Does Zoo Flexible Admin offer that as an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set CP language by member group and Zoo Flexible Admin doesn't allow language switching from any setting I see but your menus can be in any language you want specific to the member group since you are manually setting up and naming the links.

---

You can set a "Default Language" on the [**General Configuration**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/general_configuration.html#default-language) page:

[image]

Then you can override that setting per member on the [**Localization Settings**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/my_account/index.html#localization-settings) page in their My Account area:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In additional what Anna said - sometimes this can be more simple to do with sql request:

go to
**CP ->Tools -> Data -> SQL Manager -> Database Query Form**

```
UPDATE exp_members SET language="german" WHERE group_id = YOUR_GROUP_ID
```